# Inside div fits the screen but not the outer div

Tags: css

I would like to fit a div to match an outer div but, for some reason, my inner div only expands to the browser window's height.

See https://jsfiddle.net/xhv7skyd/

```
<body>
  <div id="outter">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    ....
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
  </div>
</body>
```

and the css

```
#outer {
  background: rgb(200, 100, 50);
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
}

#inner {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(0,200,0);  
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

If you need to scroll to see the entire text, then the inner div's height will be less than the outer div's.

I'm trying to adapt something to an existing template, so I don't want to modify the outer div's style, just the inner div. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: relative;` on `#outter`. Have a look at the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhv7skyd/1/)**, or look at the snippet below:

```css
#outter {
  background: rgb(200, 100, 50);
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(0,200,0);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outter">
    <div id="inner">
      
    </div>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
    All work and no play make jack a dull boy<br/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to do it without modifying outer?

Comment: Acttually, changing to relative still works for me, accepting, thanks!

Comment: @ArthurB. If you are using `absolute` positioning, then you'll have to assign `relative` positioning to the parent element in which the particular `<div>` is wrapping to make it work around it. Hope it helps!